# Balance of the current row based on two-field criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

If I have a table like this:

```
DATE        CATEGORY    QTY      SUM
01/01/2019     B         2       true
02/01/2019     B         3       true
03/01/2019     A         1       false
04/01/2019     B         3       true
05/01/2019     A         3       true
06/01/2019     A         2       true
```

I need to add the qty field by category, where the 'sum' column is true, sorting by the 'date' field. How can I get the following result using CTE in SQL Server

Result Query:

```
DATE        CATEGORY    QTY_TOTAL   SUM
01/01/2019     B           2        true
02/01/2019     B           5        true
03/01/2019     A           0        false
04/01/2019     B           8        true
05/01/2019     A           3        true
06/01/2019     A           5        true
```

PS: I looked for some similar question, but found none that could clarify my doubts completely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So if there was a category B on the 3rd which was false, would the category B on the 4th still be 8 or would the false row constitue a break in the series making it 3?

Comment: @MartinBrown If the sum column is false it just does not add, but does not subtract from the total, the sum would continue from the next line with value true

Comment: So this is just a conditional cumulative sum, @Marcoscdoni. The duplicates marked will still answer the "hard part" of the question (how to do a cumulative sum); you just need to make it a conditional `SUM` by using a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want cumulative sum :

```
select t.*, sum(case when [sum] = 'true' then qty else 0 end) over (partition by category order by [date]) as QTY_TOTAL
from table t
order by [date];
```